Azure function shows success with error 500
I have an Azure function that shows as success, but it returns error 500. I have attached a screenshot.
Azure function invocations

I have also included the setup of my function (just in case).
Azure function setup2

Azure function setup

I do not understand how error 500 can be considered a successful function. Am I missing some configuration here? Any tips?
I have looked into Application insights and logs and all seems fine (no errors reported). But on the frontend I do get error 500, an internal server error.
function.json :
{
  "scriptFile": "../application/dispatch/product/CreateProduct.js",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "products"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}

CreateProduct.ts :
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { ProducerRole } from './../../dtos/common/UserRole';
import { UserIdentity } from '@/application/dtos/common/UserIdentity';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import { logger } from '@/infrastructure/logger';
import { RequestHelper } from '@/application/helpers/RequestHelper';
import { CreateProduct } from '@/application/handlers/product/createProduct/CreateProduct.handler';
import { CreateProductRequest } from '@/application/handlers/product/createProduct/CreateProduct.request';
import { ForbiddenError } from '@/application/errors/ForbiddenError';

async function createProduct(
  userIdentity: UserIdentity,
  request?: any,
): Promise<{ status: number; body: string }> {
  logger.info('start createProduct function');

  const createProductRequest = new CreateProductRequest(userIdentity, request);

  if (createProductRequest.userRole != ProducerRole) {
    throw new ForbiddenError();
  }

  await RequestHelper.validateRequest(createProductRequest);

  const createProductHandler = container.resolve(CreateProduct);
  const response = await createProductHandler.handle(createProductRequest);

  return {
    status: 201,
    body: JSON.stringify(response),
  };
}

const createProductFunction: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest,
): Promise<void> {
  return RequestHelper.handlerRequest(context, req, createProduct);
};

export default createProductFunction;

---- EDIT ----
Details of the invocation:


It depends on what is considered an error here. Strictly, receiving a 500 response is a success in HTTP terms, since you made a request and the server responded.  In any other environment I'd be looking for the server error log to find out what has gone wrong. I can't help with that here.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular I have added the code to the question. Yeah, I was thinking the same, how come there is nothing in the log which would give me some info. I was expecting to have something similar as on the server error log

@Bob In the screenshot of Invocations you shared above, you should be able to click on the dates and slightly more information will be provided. Have you tried that yet?

But to @TangentiallyPerpendicular's point, the Status column is indicating whether the function itself ran without any issues. It is not really telling you whether the result was a 200 or a 500, for instance. If, for example, there was an auth issue that prevented the function from running, then the Status would indicate a failure.

@dacastr I have added invocation details. Nothing there either. I assume that there is some exception that is being triggered, but the strange thing is that it is not showing anywhere in the log


Azure function shows success with error 500. Am I missing some configuration here? Any tips?

I do agree with @Tangentially Perpendicular and @dacastr that when ever there is an handled exception in code, it is returning the 500  as handled exception value but not an error then it stays as success. To get a failed error you need to use exception handling and then raise/throw the error then you will get failed as status. For further use verbose to get more detailed information on the internal server exception.
So, Function success status - no exception is thrown.
Function Failed status - exception thrown.
To handle the exception and to return failed status :
  try {
    const rith_res = await RequestHelper.handlerRequest(ri_cxt, req, createProduct);
    ri_cxt.res = {
      status: rith_res.status,
      body: rith_res.body
    };
  } catch (ri_er) {
    ri_cxt.log.error('Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! ,There is an ERROR : ', ri_er);
    ri_cxt.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: `Hello Rithwik, an Error is occurred : ${ri_er.message}`
    };
  }

Also refer this SO-thread where Op is facing similar issue in python.
